# using EJB 3.1 @Startup anotation in Tomcat 7.X.X

Tags: eclipse, tomcat7, java-ee-6, startup, ejb-3.1

```
@Startup
@Singleton
public class TestTimer {
    private static int count = 0;
    @Schedule(second="*/10", minute="*", hour="*", info="MyTimer")
    public void execute() {
       System.out.println("its running count..."+count);
       count++;
    }
}
```

I want this code run on Tomcat 7.x.x, please let me know what configuration is needed for in web.xml or ejb-jar.xml to run at startup.

Answer (score 2):

Tomcat is servlet container, i.e. it's not meant to handle Enterprise Java Beans, which Singleton bean definitely is. There are ways to achieve it, but you wouldn't want to do that. An advice - use application server, it is both servlet container and EJB container.

Suggestions:

- [Glassfish](http://glassfish.java.net/) (Java EE reference implementation)
- [TomEE](http://tomee.apache.org/apache-tomee.html) (stems from OpenEJB, you'll probably find it most familiar)
- [JBoss](http://www.jboss.org/)

Comment: Agree, Tomcat is not able to understand that. TomEE definitely is. Download it and give it a try.

Comment: thanks, i use tomee-plus-1.5.1, it's going smooth but don't run my method automatically, i figure out following message from its log... INFO: Scheduler meta-data: Quartz Scheduler (v2.1.6) 'OpenEJB-TimerService-Scheduler' with instanceId 'OpenEJB'
Scheduler class: 'org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler' - running locally.
NOT STARTED.
Currently in standby mode.
Number of jobs executed: 0
Using thread pool 'org.apache.openejb.core.timer.DefaultTimerThreadPoolAdapter' - with 0 threads.
Using job-store 'org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore' - which does not support persistence. and is not clustered.

Comment: I've seen that you reposted this as a separate question, good luck with it! I have very little experience with Quartz Schedule, so cannot be of much help here.